# PHP Arrays: Count Similar outputs and display

Tags: php, arrays

What i am trying to do is get an array output of list of referrers saved in db for a certain link. i got it so far but am unable to get teh count of same referrers instead of displaying them again and again.
Here is the function i wrote :

```
<?php 

function get_links_ref($astats) {   
  $sExistedLink= '';    
  $sMyLinkSQL = "SELECT * FROM `log` WHERE `shorturl`='{$astats}' ORDER BY `click_id` DESC";    
  $aLinks = $GLOBALS['oSysDB']->getAll($sMyLinkSQL);    
  foreach ($aLinks as $astats => $aLinkInfo) {  
    $reff = $aLinkInfo['referrer']; 
    $areff = parse_url($reff);  
    if($areff['host'] == 't.co' || $areff['host'] == 'www.twitter.com' || $areff['host'] == 'api.twitter.com'){ 
      $areff['host'] = "Twitter";   
    }   
    if($areff['host'] == 'www.facebook.com' || $areff['host'] == 'm.facebook.com'){ 
      $areff['host'] = "Facebook";  
    }   
    if($areff['host'] == 'bit.ly' || $areff['host'] == 'lilink.it'){    
      $areff['host'] = "Direct";    
    }   
    $sExistedLink .= <<<EOF
      <p>{$areff['host']}</p>       
EOF;

  } 
  return $sExistedLink; 
}
```

In return i get a list like this as example : 
Facebook
Twitter
Facebook
Facebook
Twitter

Is it possible to edit this code as i can get something like this , count of total of same referrer in brackets
Facebook (3)
Twitter (2)

Comment: Hint 2: read about `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` in mysql

Comment: Please indent your code properly, it is difficult to follow without it

Comment: a little exmple code will be helpful please

Comment: @Ayaz Malik: as a programmer you should know how to program. Programming is something a *bit* more difficult than copy-pasting

Comment: Apologies, i am not a good programmer... trying to learn by doing this test scripts for my self :{ in learning process

Comment: @Ayaz Malik: so why don't you want to learn and look for ready to use solution? This way you *never* learn anything

Comment: i am considering the solution as learning properly. been gogling and trying from hours didn't got a good way to do it :{

Comment: @Ayaz Malik: well, this is a **trivial** task. If you cannot solve it - it's a good idea to start from the beginning

Comment: k Thanks zerkms, i will keep that in mind :} please consider a designer trying to be a developer.. so yeah lack of concepts :{

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your exact code with small modifications

```
function get_links_ref($astats) {   
    $sExistedLink= '';  
    $sMyLinkSQL = "SELECT * FROM `log` WHERE `shorturl`='{$astats}' ORDER BY `click_id` DESC";  
    $aLinks = $GLOBALS['oSysDB']->getAll($sMyLinkSQL);  
    foreach ($aLinks as $astats => $aLinkInfo) {    
        $reff = $aLinkInfo['referrer']; 
        $areff = parse_url($reff);  
        if($areff['host'] == 't.co' || $areff['host'] == 'www.twitter.com' || $areff['host'] == 'api.twitter.com'){ 
            $areff['host'] = "Twitter"; 
        }   
        if($areff['host'] == 'www.facebook.com' || $areff['host'] == 'm.facebook.com'){ 
            $areff['host'] = "Facebook";    
        }   
        if($areff['host'] == 'bit.ly' || $areff['host'] == 'lilink.it'){    
            $areff['host'] = "Direct";  
        }   

        if(!isset($array_count[$areff['host']])) $array_count[$areff['host']] = 0;
        $array_count[$areff['host']]++;
    }

    foreach ($array_count as $key => $value) {
        $sExistedLink .= <<<EOF
<p>$key ($value)</p>     
EOF;   
    }
   return $sExistedLink;   
}
```

Comment: it seems to be giving some errors, i am working on fixing them.

Answer (score 3):

Keep a counter as you go through the array:

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($aLinks as $astats => $aLinkInfo) {    
    $reff = $aLinkInfo['referrer'];  
    $areff = parse_url($reff);  

    if($areff['host'] == 't.co' || $areff['host'] == 'www.twitter.com' || $areff['host'] == 'api.twitter.com'){ 
        $counts["Twitter"] = isset( $counts["Twitter"]) ? ($counts["Twitter"] + 1) : 1;
    }   
    if($areff['host'] == 'www.facebook.com' || $areff['host'] == 'm.facebook.com'){ 
        $counts["Facebook"] = isset( $counts["Facebook"]) ? ($counts["Facebook"] + 1) : 1;   
    }   
    if($areff['host'] == 'bit.ly' || $areff['host'] == 'lilink.it'){    
        $counts["Direct"] = isset( $counts["Direct"]) ? ($counts["Direct"] + 1) : 1;
    }
}
```

Now, you can form the string to print it out like this:

```
foreach( $counts as $site => $count)
{
     $sExistedLink .= "<p>$site ($count)</p>";
}
```

Comment: `isset( $counts["Direct"]) ? ($counts["Direct"] + 1)` --- this copy-paste driven code can be avoided with introducing one variable with key.

Comment: k ic, but now it started giving results like this :  
facebook(1)  
facebook(2)  
facebook(3)  
instead of facebook(3)

Comment: @Ayaz - No it doesn't. You must've copied it incorrectly, or you're not printing it out correctly, because [with 10 links to Facebook it prints out Facebook one time](http://viper-7.com/qXpRlH).